# git graph has branch with no branch-off point?

Tags: git

I can't explain this other than with a screenshot:

[image: gitg graph]

What in the world does this mean? The `feat-zoo` branch seems to stem from nowhere.

EDIT:

Per requested, the script used to generate this. Run the script, look at the graph, then start over, remove the `sleep 2` calls and you'll get a different result which matches the screenshot above.

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -d .git ] || git init

ACT="rebase"

echo "blah blah" > file1.txt
echo "another file" > file2.txt
git add file1.txt file2.txt
git commit -m "MASTER C1"
sleep 2

echo "new line here" >> file1.txt
echo "new file" > file3.txt
git add file3.txt
git commit -a -m "MASTER C2"
sleep 2

echo "bug fixes" >> file1.txt
echo "bug fixes" >> file3.txt
git commit -a -m "MASTER C3"
sleep 2

git branch feat-zoo

echo "MAGICAL" >> file2.txt
git commit -am "MASTER C4"
sleep 2

git checkout feat-zoo
git $ACT master
echo "new end" >> file3.txt
git commit -am "BR C1"
sleep 2
echo "**END" >> file2.txt
git commit -am "BR C2"
sleep 2

git checkout master
sed -i 's/blah blah/WHEEE/' file1.txt
git commit -am "MASTER C5"
sleep 2

git checkout feat-zoo
git $ACT master

echo "FINAL" >> file1.txt
git commit -am "BR C3"
sleep 2

git checkout master
echo "Done" > signoff
git add signoff
git commit -m "MASTER C6"
sleep 2

git merge feat-zoo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run that script (with one change to the `sed` command, adding `-e`, so that it does the right thing on my box, and adding `-m "Merge branch 'feat-zoo'"` to the merge, so that I don't have to manually finish an edit session), it works fine with or without any "sleep 2"s.

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
*   5847d16 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'feat-zoo'
|\  
| * 42eb472 (feat-zoo) BR C3
| * 28f0d24 BR C2
| * 967e122 BR C1
* | 136b44a MASTER C6
|/  
* 437cf27 MASTER C5
* 4c0edac MASTER C4
* 6dbf80e MASTER C3
* 95c61ec MASTER C2
* 597d9ba MASTER C1
```

If I create an orphan branch and merge it in, that works fine too.

What viewer are you using to view these?  I suspect it's attempting to draw the graph, and place commits, using the commit time-stamps, and getting confused because `BR C1`'s parent is `MASTER C5` but it's already drawn `MASTER C5` above, so it has no place "below" `BR C1` to connect the next line.  When it runs out of commits to draw it just stops drawing, giving you the output you see.  Try the `git log` command above; I think it will show you the same thing I get.

(In other words, it looks like a bug in the viewer, not in git.)

Comment: Ahh! Yes indeed, it is a bug in gitg. However, it is odd that with the `sleep 2` statements, gitg then shows the graph properly.

Comment: That's why I speculate that it's using the commit timestamps.  They only carry 1-second precision, so any two commits made during the same second will have the same timestamp.  Depending on what sorting algorithm it uses and how it gets the list of revs in the first place, who knows what order it will see things.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa. It means, when you're running a shell script to simulate git actions, insert some `sleep 2` statements between commits. :) Apparently all of these ran so fast that it confused the hell out of git.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little?  This looks like you just merged a branch that started at `C1`...?  What are `C1`'s "actual" parents then?  What do you mean "confused the hell out of git"?

Comment: Apparently git doesn't like having a big sequence of commits, branches, and merges run like that (I ran these from a shell script). Maybe it has to do with time to write files? Or it somehow uses timestamps? Not sure.

Comment: Apparently you are supposing too much.

Comment: Not so. Rerunning the script generated slightly different graphs with the same exact files/commands. After inserting `sleep 2` between actions, now I get a graph that looks correct (unlike this one).

Comment: @EdwardThomson Edited post to include the script & instructions.